# Number of lines/triangles determined by n points

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can someone please illustrate how this plane works by drawing. I just want to get an idea of how this plane works.

There are n points in the plane, such that no three points are on the same line. a) How many straight lines contain a pair of these points? b) How many triangles contain three of these points as vertices? Any help would be great!

Comment: See also here for your first question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331383/number-of-straight-line-segments-determined-by-n-points-in-the-plane-is-frac

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

Given $n$ non-collinear points, there exists a distinct line for every pair of points and hence there are $\binom{n}{2}$ lines through these $n$ points.

Similarly, a triangle is uniquely determined by $3$ non-collinear points and hence the number of triangles is $\binom{n}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

User141421 has answered your question. I just want to mention that one can easily construct for any $n$,   points satisfying your hypothesis. For example, choose  any set of distinct points in  the unit circle. So you can,  for some mangeable size of $n$, construct and see.

Answer (score 0):

to form a line one needs two points

so number of possible lines is just the same as $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n^2 - n}{2}$

to form a triangle one needs three points

so number of triangles = $\binom{n}{3} = \frac{(n)(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$